# Power BI item analysis

Tags: powerbi

During my item analysis in Power BI, I calculated an EBIT per item. However my item table consist of +20 dimensions per item, think of specifics like colour, weights, material usage etc. However, there are different item groups in the same table, some of them have 2 attributes, some of them have 10 attributes, some even 20 attributes. So the headers don't have the same value, in the same column the weight and the colour could be stored for different item groups. In total I have over 200.000 items so there must be a way I guess.

I'm searching for a general way to explain the EBIT by the attributes per item per product group, which can be used in an interactive way by the Power BI user.

If I could classify it by hand, I would go over each product group, define the attributes per group (the column headers) and built over 150 item group tables with a *1 relationship to the item group code. Then I would add all of the attributes in a matrix structure, conditional format the ebit with outliers and make the page interactive so the user can filter the right attributes.

Sample of my dataset:

| ItemNo | Ebit | attribute 1 | attribute 2 | attribute 3 | attribute 4 | attribute 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | €50 | Led | Colour: blue | Lace Black | Customer own fabric |  |
| 2 | €70 | Colour Blue | Medium | Shield Cushion |  | Frame colour |

Comment: how would you classify it by hand? If you can figure that out and explain it to us, we could help. If not, not

Comment: @horseyride, thanks, elaborated the question.

Comment: How is a computer going to know that any of the items in a column are related to any other item in another column?  Colour blue is similar to Colour Blue, but if some column said Red and you wanted all of them to be in color, then you are out of automated luck.

Comment: @horseyride, since all the colour attributes for product group x are stored in a consistent column, I thought with something like a dynamic filter, it should be doable to do a deeper dive into the attributes. BUt indeed it has no numeric value.